# Methodology to solve modulus equation?

Tags: divisibility

I am trying to solve this equation

```
(d*49) % (43480 * 242343) = 1
```

for the variable d.  I was attempting to use the Extended Euclidean algorithm but am not sure how to set everything up and iterate through to get d. Can someone please help me get it set up at least to use the algorithm? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The equation you gave is equivalent to $49d-1=43480\times242343k$ where $k$ is an integer. You can apply Extended Euclidean Algorithm to solve for $d$. When you are done, take all values of $d$ such that $0\leq d \leq 43480\times242343$.